# Windows task scehduler not fully completing a task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, nunit-console

I have some Nunit automated tests.  I am trying to use Nunit console to run those tests over Selenium grid.  I have created a .bat file to launch the tests over the grid, which looks at a list of tests in a text file.

When I manually run the .bat file, my tests run and I get an xml results file automatically created.

When I get windows task scheduler to run the .bat file, my tests will run, however, I do NOT get my test results.

Need help understanding why I do not get my results if I use task scheduler.

Here is the .bat file contents;

```
nunit-console /result:console-testResults2.xml /work:C:\Selenium\TestResults /runlist:C:\Selenium\testlist.txt "C:\Selenium\VisualStudio\Automated Tests\Automated Tests\AutomatedTests\bin\Debug\AutomatedTests.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turns out it was because of where it runs the tests from. Once I set the "Start In" option to the same directory as my test dll, then it created the XML file in that directory fine.